# How to create folders recursively in googledrive through api?

Tags: google-drive-api

For example, I'm going to upload a file `scenery.jpg` to `/images/2020/03/18/` directory, if I upload to OneDrive, the upload url going to be like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/images/2020/03/18/scenery.jpg
```

I don't have to know if the `images` folder, the `2020`, `03` and `18` folder exists or not, OneDrive will auto create it recursively, acting like Object-based Storage.

---

But now, I'm going to upload it to GoogleDrive and GoogleDrive seems can't create folders recursively(as far as I know, see [Create and populate folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder)), now I have 2 questions:

1、Is that I have to check if these folders exists one by one to make sure if I have to create these folders?
`/images/`
`/images/2020/`
`/images/2020/03/`
`/images/2020/03/18/`
2、If none of above folder exists, is that I have to create these four folders one by one(means request api four times)?

Anyone who did this before? I hope what I assume is wrong, because it's too complicated to do it in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unfortunately you are correct

Google handles file and folder hierarchy in a different way and indeed the only way create / list nested files and folders is to iterate recursively.

Also, if you want to know if a file / folder already exists with the method [Files:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get), you need to know the file / folder ID, rather than just the name. If you do not know the ID, than you need to [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) all files on your drive / (unless you specify a certain folder as the parent folder, e.g. `'1234567' in parents` with the  [query parameter `q`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)).

The same applies for creation. If you create a folder which you want to be a subfolder of a different parent folder - you also need to create the parent folder.

However, it is not as complicated as you may think.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59966382/11599789) is one of many available samples of how to list the contents of all subfolders and subfolders of subfolders dynamically - in your case you would just need to add the condition to create a certain folder if it is not contained in the list.

You would need to take some time to study the working principle of Drive API, however once you get an understanding it is not complicated.

Comment: God, how I wish my assumption is wrong, I don't understand why GoogleDrive doesn't do like OneDrive(it's supper easy), but thank you anyway.